# Android - MediaPlayer Crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, media-player

I'm making an android application that plays music. When I run it, I get a NullPointer exception, and I have no clue why!!

Here is the code in my onCreate() in my activity:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tekno);
    mp.start();
```

Here is my log cat:

```
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255): create failed:
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:735)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at com.jlennon.gametest.PlayGameActivity.onCreate(PlayGameActivity.java:31)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 17:09:51.530: D/AndroidRuntime(19255): Shutting down VM
06-03 16:36:23.340: W/dalvikvm(15997): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a431f8)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jlennon.gametest/com.jlennon.gametest.PlayGameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at com.jlennon.gametest.PlayGameActivity.onCreate(PlayGameActivity.java:32)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    06-03 16:36:23.350: E/AndroidRuntime(15997):    ... 11 more
```

What I;m getting from this is that my MediaPlayer.create() is returning null, and I guess that must have something to do with my file.  My music file is tekno.wav.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
06-03 17:09:51.520: D/MediaPlayer(19255): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

It seems your WAV file isn't readable by Android for some reason. See the links below for some information that may be relevant:

[setDataSourceFd Failed](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/152/topics/9144)

[MediaPlayer.setDataSource causes IOException for valid file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752082/321697)

Comment: This solved my problem. I downloaded a mp3 click-sound from the internet and wasn't able to instantiate a MediaPlayer with it. After reconverting it with Audacity in worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi, I'm also in troubles with this issue. Could you please explain what does "reconverting" it means? You meant to convert a mp4 to avi and then this avi to mp4?

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `getApplicationContext`, this might return `null`.
Maybe that's what happened here as well.

So for example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tekno);
```

Comment: I have done this, and it still doesn't work.  My mediaPlayer is returning null, what could cause this?

Comment: Maybe your sound file is corrupt. Try another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tekno);
mp.start();
```