# Android MediaPlayer error(-1, 4) on prepare()

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaPlayer instance for local audio files.
It worked, but after some changes (bad for me, can't figure out what exactly it was) this error began to appear:
//message

Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC

//in LogCat

```
error(-1, 4)
MEDIA_ERROR(mPreparySync) signal application thread
```

So, what are possible reasons? File to play exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 've gotten this error evertime I've tried to play a non supported file format like wmv. So I'd check that first
Check these links:
[Android MediaPlayer not preparing. Error (1, -4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970574/android-mediaplayer-not-preparing-error-1-4)
and
[MediaPlayer.setDataSource causes IOException for valid file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657280/mediaplayer-setdatasource-causes-ioexception-for-valid-file)?

Comment: Tried .mp3 and .ogg, no luck. Both are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the blue i would guess the file format does not fit

Answer (score 0):

Check the file path first, make sure you have a valid Uri. An other reason would be that you instanciate to many players.