# IOException when playing .mp4 with android mediaplayer

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, mp4, sd-card

I am trying to play a .mp4 file in MediaPlayer but it always throws an IOException at mediaplayer.prepare():

> 09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14937/com.alex.videoplayertest E/MediaPlayer﹕ error     (-2147483648, 0)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕  java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x80000000
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at com.alex.videoplayertest.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:53)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   09-21 12:59:33.570  14926-14926/com.alex.videoplayertest W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    String file = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/media/Light_Bulb.mp4";

    File f = new File(file);
    if (f.exists())
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(file));
            fileInputStream.close();
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: Did you set your permissions?

Comment: yes, i have added permission write external storage. do i need something else?

Comment: Does the file exist at that location? You can check with file.exists();

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
String file= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Download/media/_29187_v.1_Light_Bulb_16HD_25fps.mp4";

File f = new File(file);
```

And also add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your Manifest file

Comment: which line refers to MainActivity.java:53?

Comment: mediaPlayer.prepare() is at line 53.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657280/mediaplayer-setdatasource-causes-ioexception-for-valid-file check this link

Comment: but i have a video file and not an audio file

Answer (score 0):

I have now a solution for my problem. 
 I don't really know why with MediaPlayer it is not possible to play this video in my test application but with VideoView it is.

Here is my code with Videoview:

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity
{
VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/media/Light_Bulb.mp4";

    File f = new File(file);
    if (f.exists())
    {
        videoView.setMediaController(null);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(file));
    }

    findViewById(R.id.closeVideoView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (videoView != null)
        videoView.stopPlayback();
}
```