# A strange issue with MediaPlayer on Android version 9 - null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer, android-9.0-pie

Recently I changed my smartphone to Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 (Android 9) and wanted to test one of my applications on it.
The application does not start because there is some problem with `MediaPlayer`. Which does not appear on any smartphone or tablet on which I tested the application(even on much weaker than note 7). However, they all worked on the older version of the android.

Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: aaa.aaa.aa, PID: 25635
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener)' on a null object reference
                  at aaa.aaa.aa.MyActivity.prepare_media_minigun(MyActivity.java:6789)
                  at aaa.aaa.aa.MyActivity.onClick(MyActivity.java:4176)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
                  at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
                  at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)


E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player
D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
           java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
               at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
               at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1304)
               at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:998)
               at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:971)
```

My code:

```
static void prepare_media_minigun() {
    for (int i = 0; i < minigun_max_ammo; i++) {
        media_minigun[i] = new MediaPlayer();

        if (minigun_silencer == false) {
            media_minigun[i] = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.minigun);
        } else {
            media_minigun[i] = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.minigun2);
        }

        media_minigun[i].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }

    minigun_player_unloaded = false;
}
```

Array of `MediaPlayers`:

```
public static   MediaPlayer[] media_minigun = new MediaPlayer[100] ;
```

The `prepare_media_minigun()` method is called in `OnCreate()`.

Maybe someone has already encountered that error, because I do not have any ideas how to solve it. This seems to be a problem with loading sounds from the raw folder.

I installed this application on OnePlus 7 with android 9.0 and it also does not work. It seems that the problem is something in this version of android.

Comment: Have you tried reencoding the audio file into a different format? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752082/11713280) suggests that an unsupported format could be a possible source for the exception.

Comment: The original sound is in mp3 format. I tried WAV and OGG but it did`t help.